# how to rewrite a query that uses a subquery on self as a join

Tags: sql, db2, subquery, self-join

How do I rewrite the following query as a join? I think rewriting it as a join would perform better (I'm theorizing) but I'm having hard time getting the join right. Any help is much appreciated.

```
SELECT O.JOBNUM, O.JOBNAME, O.STARTTS, 
(SELECT 
    MIN(I.STARTTS)
 FROM TABLE1 AS I
 WHERE 
    I.STARTTS > O.STARTTS AND 
    I.JOBNAME = O.JOBNAME) 
 AS ENDTS
 FROM TABLE1 AS O;
```

Basically, the above query is used to retrieve the ENDTS of any given task instance. The ENDTS is not saved and is calculated automatically as the same tasks run in a loop so the ENDTS of any given task is the the STARTTS of the same task (identified by name) when it runs again. If a task has not finished running yet, a NULL is fine for the ENDTS.

Thanks you for your help in advance.

Comment: I'm not sure the left join is the right solution.  It may simply be a query optimization issue.  Do you have indexes on Startts and Jobname?

Comment: Inner and outer are bith keywords, try to avoid using them as table/column nakes as much as possible.

Comment: @Narnian. Yep. I do have the indexes but the join that bluefeet proposed below performs better.

Comment: @wildplasser Thanks. I changed it per your suggestin in my setup.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to rewrite this as a `JOIN`, then you can use:

```
SELECT o.JOBNUM, 
    o.JOBNAME, 
    o.STARTTS, 
    MIN(i.STARTTS) ENDTS
FROM TABLE1 AS o
LEFT JOIN TABLE1 AS i
    ON i.STARTTS > o.STARTTS 
    AND i.JOBNAME = o.JOBNAME
 GROUP BY o.JOBNUM, o.JOBNAME, o.STARTTS;
```

Comment: Thanks bluefeet. This is great and it works well. If I add a WHERE clause for ENDTS, it would cause a tablescan instead of using the STARTTS index. Do you know if there is a way around this? I have the same problem with the original query with the subselect as well.

Comment: Actually, it makes sense to me now. If I just add ENDTS in the where clause, then it would need a tablescan but if I add JOBNAME or STARTS as well, it wouldn't do a full tablescan. From what I know, we can't create on index on ENDTS in the view (I think it is possible on sql server but not on db2).

Comment: @Azeem unfortunately I am not that familiar with db2.